# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS] - can't uninstall or run adb commands

Tags: installation

I know this issue has been discussed several times, but in every discussion the final solutions are only:

- unistall the application and reinstall it
- install it by adb command adb install -r apkname.apk

this two solutions works, but they are not suitable solutions for me, since the moment we distribute the apk to the customer through a platform called afaria, and there is a little android application installed on the customer's device that, if there are some apk in a given directory, runs the following script (that i know for sure that works)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

the problem is that the application installation fails, due to the [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS] error (i'm 100% sure the certificate is the same). We can't tell to the customer to unistall the application (or to execute an adb command!!!) before launching our installer application, it must be a fully automated system. Please help me, i'm desperate!!!
I think that if am able to simulate by code the -r option of the adb install command i will solve the problem, but i can't find a way to achieve this.

If someone can help me, he well be my heroe!!! :)